# Can I ignore message/delivery-status in mail client?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, mime-types

How I did understand, message/delivery-status is a mime type of message part,

> which contains the data formatted for the mail server to read (Wiki)

Does it mean that I can ignore it while receiving message from mail server? If not, could you give more explanation of present mime type.

How should I parse it and do I need to present it to user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it on official specifications https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464#section-2.1

Comment: See the [com.sun.mail.dsn pacakge](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/package-summary.html).